# What are the food behaviors of anorexic patients?

Tags: terminology, behavior, obsessive-compulsive, anorexia, eating-disorder

I'm a medical student reading a book about nutrition and Metabolism. In the description of Anorexia nervosa patients the writer states that

> She has a preoccupation with, and often a considerable knowledge of, food and frequently has a variety of stylised compulsive behaviour patterns associated with food.

What does 'stylised compulsive behaviour patterns associated with food' mean?

Comment: think counting, weighing, diarizing, chewing a specific number of chews, matching each bite of food to something else such as drinking water or performing a time consuming action, .... each person will have their own actions but they will not be what you would consider normal or common.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you so much!

Comment: @KateGregory Could you make that into an answer? Battling the low answer percentage ;)

Comment: @Narusan I don't have any citations or studies for that, it's just something I know.

Comment: @KateGregory It doesn't matter in this case because OPs requesting examples (as I understand it). A case study would suffice, or just nothing at all.